# How do you use ORMLite with an abstract class?

Tags: android, ormlite

I have an base class `Peripheral`. Classes `Sensor` and `Master` are extensions of `Peripheral`. I need ORMlite to instantiate my Peripheral objects that were previously saved. Obviously any attempt to instantiate `Peripheral` reflectively will result in a `ClassInstantiationException` due to its abstractness. How can I have ORMlite load any `Peripheral` object since `Peripheral` is abstract?

Here is the sample of what I am doing:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName="Peripheral")
abstract class Peripheral {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId="true")
    int _ID;
    @DatabaseField
    int mSerial;
}

class Sensor extends Peripheral {
}

class Master extends Peripheral {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I have ORMlite load any Peripheral object since Peripheral is abstract?

I think your problem stemmed from the fact that the `@DatabaseTable` needs to be on the `Sensor` and `Master` classes.  It won't hurt it to also be on the base class but it won't be detected there.

This will have one table named `"Peripheral"` used for both super-classes.  Any fields (such as `mSerial`) from the base class will be detected and used as fields in both of the super-classes.

The only limitation is that ORMLite is unable to differentiate between `Sensor` and `Master`.  It right now is missing the feature which allows you to get all rows that are a `Sensor` and get all rows that are a `Master`.  Also, it cannot generate the schema for them if the super-classes have their own fields marked with `@DatabaseField`.

*Edit:*

It's important to reiterate that [ORMlite](http://ormlite.com/) (as of 3/2013) does not support multiple sub-classes *in the same table*.  Subclasses *will* inherit the database fields from the base class but they have to each be in their own table. Here's a [discussion about this topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ormlite-dev/U-LExLQBAws) on the mailing list.

To accomplish this, you could have 3 tables: 1 for the base class information and 2 for the sub-classes.  The sub-class tables would have a foreign key to the associated base class row.

Comment: Thank you sir for hunting me down. I appreciate it.

Comment: No worries @AedonEtLIRA.  I've been meaning to answer and had my answer almost finished when it was deleted.  :-(   Feel free to ask more questions if my answer doesn't completely take care of you question.

Comment: Ya, foul play on my part. I really should have answered it before deleting it.

Comment: To clear up the original question ormlite will not work with abstract classes due to reflection so a "workaround" must be used.

Comment: Really @J.Romero?  Can you be more specific?  Lot of people are using it with abstract classes.

Comment: @Gray I can setup a quick pastebin but as @AedonEtLIRA stated originally using a true abstract class will result in a `ClassInstantiationException`

Comment: I'd love to see a pastebin.  I have pretty good test coverage around abstract classes @J.Romero but I'm sure there are conditions I'm not covering.

Comment: @Gray, here is the sample code I've come up with, maybe you can point out what I might be doing wrong: https://github.com/jromero/ORLite-Examples-Android/tree/master/src/com/j256/ormlite/examples/abstracted/data

Comment: Right.  ORMLite does not support multiple subclasses in the _same_ table @J.Romero.  I've edited my answer to provide more details.  See this discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ormlite-dev/U-LExLQBAws

Comment: @Gray Can we do that (3 tables, 1 base class 2 sub-classes) without changing the model ? Cause it's a DBMS matter. My "pojo's" model should not be impacted.

Answer (score 0):

Gray is correct, and I forgot about that reflection rule when I asked the question the first time. I have worked around the limitations on both limits of reflection and ORMlite not currently distiguishing between super classes. This is my structure:

```
class Peripheral {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId)
    int _ID;
    @databaseField
    int serial;
    // ... Methods ommitted to be succint
}

class PeripheralWrapper extends Peripheral {
    final Peripheral mBase;
    PeripheralWrapper(Peripheral peripheral) {
        mBase = peripheral;
    }
    // ... Methods are overridden but call the base's methods instead
}

class Sensor extends PeripheralWrapper {
    Sensor(Peripheral peripheral) {
        super(peripheral);
    }
}

class Master extends PeripheralWrapper {
    Master(Peripheral peripheral) {
        super(peripheral);
    }
}

// This is the work around

@DatabaseTable(tableName="Peripheral")
class BasePeripheral extends Peripheral {
}
```

This work around is simple actually. Now I only inflate the basePeripheral and then pass those into the wrappers as needed. All inflation and delegation of wrapping is done in a PeripheralFactory.