# ORMLite and inheritance (for Android)

Tags: android, inheritance, persistence, ormlite

I want to persist some classes that must implement an interface like this:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "conditions")
abstract public class Condition implements Configurable {

    @DatabaseField(id = true, foreign = true)
    private Accion belong_to;

    @DatabaseField
    private HashMap<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();

    @DatabaseField
    protected String className = this.getClass().getName();

    protected final HashMap<String, String> getConfig() {/* */}
    protected final void setConfig(HashMap<String, String> config) {/* */}
    protected void setConfig(String string, String value) {/* */}
    abstract public String getName();
    abstract public int getImageResource();
    abstract public String getShortDesc();
}
```

The thing is, I have to instantiate the correct child of `Condition` when I create them (as Condition itself is abstract).

Is there any way I can do that when writing the DAO (I record className for that purpose)? Or should I do this in any other way?

My `Accion` objects should have one `Condition` object attached. Accion is also persisted, so the way to get the Conditions is via Dao also.

---

**Update:** I am now using `public interface Configurable extends Serializable { /*...*/ }` so that Java may serialize the Configurable object, and I will store it in the Accion object.

Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Classes stored should not be abstract classes due to `ClassInstantiationException` because class reflection is used to instantiate the retrieved records.

There is a work around posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569751/how-do-you-use-ormlite-with-an-abstract-class/11569794#comment21389971_11569794) using wrapper classes but my method so far has been to store the "class", in my case serverType, as a field and when retrieving the base class passing the base class to a constructor of the wanted child class and copy it's properties.

**Usage**

```
        Dao<BaseConnectionInfo, Integer> connections = DatabaseManager
                .getInstance(this).getDatabaseHelper()
                .getDao(BaseConnectionInfo.class);

        BaseConnectionInfo connection = connections.queryForId(1);

        if (connection.isServerType(BaseConnectionInfo.SERVER_TYPE_MSSQL)) {
            connection = new MsSqlConnectionInfo(connection);
        } else if (connection
                .isServerType(BaseConnectionInfo.SERVER_TYPE_MYSQL)) {
            connection = new MySqlConnectionInfo(connection);
        }
```

**BaseConnectionInfo**

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "connections")
public class BaseConnectionInfo implements SqlDriverInterface {

    public static final String TAG = "BaseConnection";

    public static final String SERVER_TYPE_MYSQL = "MYSQL";
    public static final String SERVER_TYPE_MSSQL = "MSSQL";
    public static final String SERVER_TYPE_SYBASE = "SYBASE";
    public static final String SERVER_TYPE_POSTGRESQL = "POSTGRESQL";

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField
    protected String serverType;

    @DatabaseField
    private String name;

    ...

    public boolean isServerType(String serverType) {
        return this.serverType.equals(serverType);
    }

    ...
}
```

**MySqlConnectionInfo**

```
public class MySqlConnectionInfo extends BaseConnectionInfo {

    public MySqlConnectionInfo() {
        // FOR ORMLITE
        serverType = SERVER_TYPE_MYSQL;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor used to convert {@link BaseConnectionInfo} to
     * {@link MySqlConnectionInfo}
     * 
     * @param baseConnectionInfo
     */
    public MySqlConnectionInfo(BaseConnectionInfo b) {
        setId(b.getId());
        setName(b.getName());
        setHost(b.getHost());
        setOptionsJson(b.getOptionsJson());
    }
    ...
}
```

**MsSqlConnectionInfo**

```
public class MsSqlConnectionInfo extends BaseConnectionInfo {

    public MsSqlConnectionInfo() {
        // FOR ORMLITE
        serverType = SERVER_TYPE_MSSQL;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor used to convert {@link BaseConnectionInfo} to
     * {@link MsSqlConnectionInfo}
     * 
     * @param baseConnectionInfo
     */
    public MsSqlConnectionInfo(BaseConnectionInfo b) {
        setId(b.getId());
        setName(b.getName());
        setHost(b.getHost());
        setOptionsJson(b.getOptionsJson());
    }
    ...
 }
```